# ListView handled by it's parent ScrollView

Tags: android

First of all: I know that a ListView has it's own "scrollview" but I need a solution for the next issue:

I need to show a ListView with a first item completly different from the other items. Now I'm implementing it with the two type row's solution. But as I've said before: first row and other rows have nothing in common, and there's no common veiws inside them at all. Due to this I cannot recycle rows when user scrolls.

Are there any solution for show a first item and a listView ALL scrollable?

Thanks![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZemzZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can override `getItemViewType(int position)` method of ListView Adapter for which you need to use two type of viewType, first for  header and one for all other item Views. Then all recycling  will be  handle by ListView Adapter.Better you use RecyclerView as it makes use of ViewHolder pattern  compulsory, which is a nice thing. You can see link https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think the one you need is similar to this one

https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView

This one providing the treeView with scrollView

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy. You just need to extend your adapter from [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). Baseadapter lets you set different layouts for your children which in your case is a layout for first item and another for the rest. By the way it is worthy to look at [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) which is a pretty strong replacement for ListView

Answer (score -1):

You may force your `ListView` to fully extends to its height using this snippet:

```
public static void getTotalHeightofListView(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    int totalHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        mView.measure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.w("HEIGHT" + i, String.valueOf(totalHeight));

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
        + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```

That way your `ScrollView` will be in charge of handling the screen scroll, and you may add a view on top of the `ListView` without breaking the recycling process.